# How to pass GCP private json key as String instead of passing file path in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-authentication

We are running Spark hosted on a private data center and trying to read the data from GCP storage. I'm using below code snippet to read `.csv`.

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf
    sparkConf.setAppName("gcp-storage-reader")
    sparkConf.setMaster("local[*]")
    sparkConf.set("google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile", "<json key file>")

val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate()

sparkSession
     .read
     .csv("gs://input/test.csv")
     .show(2)
```

Is there anyway to pass the `.json` key content, instead of path to the private key json. For example, we can access the [BigQuery](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector) by setting `spark.conf.set("credentials", "<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_IN_BASE64>")`. Can we do the same for reading the data from GCP Storage as well?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer, we can do the service account authentication by setting the below configuration in `sparkConf` bean,

```
sparkConf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key.id", "<privateKeyId>")
sparkConf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key", "<privateKey>")
sparkConf.set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.email", "<clientEmail>")
```

This way we can **avoid** passing the private JSON key file path and pass directly the key information.

Comment: This has stopped working with dataproc 2.1 (spark 3.3)