# Error Connecting to GCS using Private Keys

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc

Scenario is that we have Project1 from where we are trying to access Project2 GCS.
We are passing private key of project 2 to SparkSession and job is running in project 1 but it is giving Invalid PKCS8 data.

Dataproc version - 1.4

```
session.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key.id","<private-key-id>");
session.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.private.key",<private-key>");
session.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.gs.auth.service.account.email","<client-email>");
```

ERROR:

```
2022-02-17T16:19:09.231359147Z DEFAULT Invalid PKCS8 data.   at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.CredentialFactory.privateKeyFromPkcs8(CredentialFactory.java:346)    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.CredentialFactory.getCredentialsFromSAParameters(CredentialFactory.java:310)   at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.CredentialFactory.getCredential(CredentialFactory.java:393)   at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.getCredential(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1324)    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.createGcsFs(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1459) at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.configure(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1443)  at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.initialize(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:467)  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3242)    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:121)   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3291)   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3259)   at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:470)   at com.gcp.util.Day2Util.deleteGCSPartFile(Day2Util.java:430)    at com.gcp.ReadGCSWithSA.main(ReadGCSWithSA.java:42)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)   at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52) at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:855)   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)  at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:939) at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:948)   at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Please let me know if there is any other way to pass the SA details. Please note we don't have the access to pass service account credential file.

Comment: I don't find the properties you used above in https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/hadoop-connectors/blob/master/gcs/CONFIGURATION.md#authentication. Where do you get them?

Comment: It worked now, actually i removed -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END PRIVATE KEY----- hence it was not working. I found these property in one of the stack overflow post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68742058/how-to-pass-gcp-private-json-key-as-string-instead-of-passing-file-path-in-apach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked fine with above properties. Problem was I removed -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- and -----END PRIVATE KEY----- from private_key earlier hence it was not working

Answer (score 5):

If you are using [GCP Service Account Credential (known as CSA)](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#service-account) as Java string, make sure to escape `"` and `\n` with
`\"` and `\\n`.

**Example:**

```
String fakeCreds = "{\"type\": \"service_account\", \"project_id\": \"test\"....}";

GoogleCredentials credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials
  .fromStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(fakeCreds.getBytes()))
  .createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam");
```

**Note:** `private_key` has "new lines" in it. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privacy-Enhanced_Mail

Example:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nprivate__key\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

Comment: Dude you solved me an issue of +1hr, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same issue, on inspecting there was a white line of space after -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY. On Linux I had pasted the whole content via terminal 'nano' editor. Pasting the content or file via WinSCP fixed this.