# Passing the credentials as a Json object instead of in a file

Tags: google-analytics-api

The two methods to pass the credentials as shown in https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/migration/api/reporting-ua-to-ga4#node.js require a file containing the credentials in Json format.

Is there a way to pass the credentials directly as a Json object?

I am coding in Node.js.

Comment: Is this link somewhat helpful ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68742058/how-to-pass-gcp-private-json-key-as-string-instead-of-passing-file-path-in-apach. Perhaps you could keep the private key in an environmental configuration file and then read it from there instead of passing a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way I could think of :

The `BetaAnalyticsDataClient` API includes a property called `credentials` that takes as input `private_key` and `client_email`. So instead of using `keyFilename`, you could use set the `credentials` property to pass the required credentials.

**UPDATE**

You could store the `private_key` in a secure mannner in your environmental configuration file.

Reference link - [BetaAnalyticsDataClient API](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/analytics-data/latest/v1beta.BetaAnalyticsDataClient.html)